# UIActivityViewController 101 - Anything will be helpful

Tags: ios, email, twitter, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIActivityViewController - Email and Twitter sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984403/uiactivityviewcontroller-email-and-twitter-sharing)

I'm starting to get familiar with the new iOS 6 way to share: *UIActivityViewController* (the same as when you share a photo from the native iOS photo app), but I'm experiencing a few problems. First, when I choose to share via email, I **can't find a way to set the subject of the email**. Second, when I post on twitter, I can't find how to post a URL (except explicitly writing it in a NSString).

Before, on iOS 5, I was using *MFMailComposeViewController* for Mail and *SLComposeViewController* for Twitter. It worked well. If there's no way to choose the subject with *UIActivityViewController*, could there be a way that I put my own custom buttons on the ActivityViewController, buttons that will call *MFMailComposeViewController* and *SLComposeViewController* when touched? I'm just speculating here.

Thanks!

Comment: For the URL just put `NSURL` object in activity items array. I don't know how to add the subject to the e-mail :)

Comment: Then, do you know if it's possible to do a custom button with mail's icon that when pressed goes to my same IBAction as in iOS 5 when I used MFMailComposeViewController and set the subject?

Comment: I've **[answered][1]** this in another question you have posted.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984403/uiactivityviewcontroller-email-and-twitter-sharing/12984541#12984541

Answer (score -1):

I've **[answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984403/uiactivityviewcontroller-email-and-twitter-sharing/12984541#12984541)** this in another question you have posted.

```
NSString *text = @"My mail text";

NSURL *recipients = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:me@example.com?subject=Hi"];

NSArray *activityItems = @[text, recipients];

UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                            initWithActivityItems:activityItems 
                                            applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: @BryanH the code already had an array. It uses the new Container Literals for NSArrays, etc. `@[]`. You can read more here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: Thanks! I initially pasted that line with the literals into a project and got an error, so I assumed it was incorrect. It turns out that project was using an older LLVM. Bumping up the version made the error go away.